# Reactの処理のコンポーネント化に失敗する

Tags: reactjs, next.js

#### 前提

現在ポートフォリオサイトを作成しています。
https://github.com/takoyan33/manga-kousatu.net
https://mangakousatunet.vercel.app/

#### 実現したいこと

現在ポートフォリオで作成していおり、
登録処理をコンポーネント化したいと考えています。
https://mangakousatunet.vercel.app/register
登録処理はFirebase authcationを利用しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

ですが、ファイルを２つに分けて、signup.jsを作り、コンポーネント化しようとしたのですが、
上手くコンポーネント化されずに、クリックしても反応がない状態です。
関数を他ファイルに書くのが初めてなので、どこがおかしいか分からない状態です。
分かる方がいればよろしくお願いします。

```
#register.js
import { app } from "../firebaseConfig";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { MuiNavbar } from "../layouts/components/MuiNavbar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
 import SignUp from "./api/auth/signup";

export default function Register() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


  const SignUpWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider).then((response: any) => {
      console.log(response.user);
      sessionStorage.setItem("Token", response.user.accessToken);
      router.push("/home");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>漫画考察.net/新規登録</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <MuiNavbar />
      <div className="max-w-7xl m-auto">
        <h2 className="m-5 my-12 text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
          新規登録
        </h2>

        <Box
          component="form"
          className="flex justify-center max-w-7xl "
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
        >
          <div>
            <label className="text-center my-4">メールアドレス*</label>
            <br></br>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="sample@gmail.com"
              className="m-auto w-80"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <label className="text-center my-4">パスワード（8文字以上)*</label>
            <br></br>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              variant="outlined"
              className="m-auto w-80"
              onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <label className="text-center my-4">
              確認用パスワード（8文字以上)*
            </label>
            <br></br>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              variant="outlined"
              className="m-auto w-80"
              onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={SignUp}
              className="m-auto w-80 my-8"
            >
              新規登録
            </Button>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={SignUpWithGoogle}
              className="m-auto w-80 "
            >
              Googleで新規登録
            </Button>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Button variant="outlined" className="m-auto w-80 my-8">
              <Link href="/login">ログインはこちら</Link>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Box>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
#signup.js

import { app } from "../../../firebaseConfig";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";

export const SignUp = () => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((response) => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("Token", response.user.accessToken);
      console.log(response.user.accessToken);
      router.push("/home");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("emailが既にあります");
    });

  return SignUp;
};
```

成功している処理

```
#register.js
import { app } from "../firebaseConfig";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { MuiNavbar } from "../layouts/components/MuiNavbar";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Register() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const SignUp = () => {
    let checkSaveFlg = window.confirm("この内容で登録しても大丈夫ですか？");

    if (checkSaveFlg) {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((response: any) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("Token", response.user.accessToken);
          console.log(response.user.accessToken);
          router.push("/home");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert("emailが既にあります");
        });
    } else {
    }
  };
  const SignUpWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider).then((response: any) => {
      console.log(response.user);
      sessionStorage.setItem("Token", response.user.accessToken);
      router.push("/home");
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>漫画考察.net/新規登録</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <MuiNavbar />
      <div className="max-w-7xl m-auto">
        <h2 className="m-5 my-12 text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
          新規登録
        </h2>

        <Box
          component="form"
          className="flex justify-center max-w-7xl "
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
        >
          <div>
            <label className="text-center my-4">メールアドレス*</label>
            <br></br>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="sample@gmail.com"
              className="m-auto w-80"
              variant="outlined"
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <label className="text-center my-4">パスワード（8文字以上)*</label>
            <br></br>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              variant="outlined"
              className="m-auto w-80"
              onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <label className="text-center my-4">
              確認用パスワード（8文字以上)*
            </label>
            <br></br>
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              variant="outlined"
              className="m-auto w-80"
              onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={SignUp}
              className="m-auto w-80 my-8"
            >
              新規登録
            </Button>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={SignUpWithGoogle}
              className="m-auto w-80 "
            >
              Googleで新規登録
            </Button>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <Button variant="outlined" className="m-auto w-80 my-8">
              <Link href="/login">ログインはこちら</Link>
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Box>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ところで、GitHubでコードを公開されており、それをVercelに公開されているのであればプルリクエストベースで作業されると[ブランチ・PRごとにプレビュー環境が用意できる](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#preview-branches)のでおすすめですよ。現状をmainブランチとは分けて共有できます。もちろんプレビューも共有するにはビルドは通っている必要がありますが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

処理を外部化したいのかUIを外部化したいのかで方向性がかわりますが、UIの分離を行うという理解で回答します

componentsフォルダをpagesと同じ階層に作成する想定です
`SingUp` をコンポーネント名にしているため、イベント処理の関数名をSignUpから `OnSignUp` に変更しています

```
// components/SignUp.tsx
export default function SignUp() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

  const onSignUp = () => {
  };

  const onSignUpWithGoogle = () => {
  }; 

  return (
    <>
        <h2 className="m-5 my-12 text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
            新規登録
        </h2>
        <Box
        component="form"
        className="flex justify-center max-w-7xl "
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
    >
        <!-- ログインUI省略 -->
        </Box>
    </>    
  )
}
```

```
// pages/register.tsx
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp";

export default function Register() {
  // 省略

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>漫画考察.net/新規登録</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <MuiNavbar />
      <div className="max-w-7xl m-auto">
        <!-- SignUpコンポーネントを使用 -->
        <SignUp />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ファイルを分けてUI表示のみの回答例ですが、まずはコンポーネントを読み込んで表示を試してみてはいかがでしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事分けることができました。最初はここから始めようと思います。